# Is Stack Overflow Meta incorrectly configured?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

If I call the Auth "sites" API, then it shows Meta Stack Overflow as:

```
  "name": "Meta Stack Overflow",
  "logo_url": "http://sstatic.net/stackoverflowmeta/img/logo.png",
  "api_endpoint": "http://api.meta.stackoverflow.com",
  "site_url": "http://meta.stackoverflow.com",
  "description": "Q&A for the Stack Exchange engine powering these sites",
  "icon_url": "http://sstatic.net/stackoverflowmeta/img/apple-touch-icon.png",
  "state": "normal",
  "styling": {
    "link_color": "#3D3D3D",
    "tag_foreground_color": "#6F6F6F",
    "tag_background_color": "#E7E7E7"
```

Is the "normal" state incorrect here? Or is Stack Overflow a "special" case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is expected behavior, Meta Stack Overflow is indeed a special case - see the original [Per-Site Metas announcement](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/new-per-site-metas/), specifically the last paragraph:

> For now we are leaving
>   meta.stackoverflow.com grandfathered
>   in, as-is, with no changes; it’s still
>   a standalone community with a
>   standalone reputation system. We think
>   Stack Overflow is large enough to
>   justify this, and it just so happens
>   that Stack Overflow is also the name
>   of the company, too. Meta Stack
>   Overflow will serve as the “National
>   Capital” where we process feedback not
>   just for Stack Overflow but for the
>   core engine itself — while the smaller
>   meta sites are akin to regional or
>   state capitals.

I've submitted a follow up question [Shouldn't you take the plunge and have a per-site Meta for Stack Overflow too in favor of meta.stackexchange.com?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/58159/shouldnt-you-take-the-plunge-and-have-a-per-site-meta-for-stack-overflow-too-in) back then, and [Jeff Atwoods answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/58159/shouldnt-you-take-the-plunge-and-have-a-per-site-meta-for-stack-overflow-too-in/58203#58203) indicates that this isn't going to change anytime soon, though still something they *might* reconsider in the future.